# Silverlight 4 PagedCollectionView with Multiple Filters

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to Silverlight 4 and the PagedCollectionView.  I know it's possible to add a filter to a PCV such as

pvc.Filter = new Predicate(FilterProjectId);

Where pvc is a populated PagedCollectionView.

What I need to do is stack multiple filters to a PCV as I've got a search screen with about 6 fields on it and a DataGrid that's bound to the PCV.  Depending on what ComboBoxes are selected, when a search button is pressed, I need to filter the PCV results based on those selections.

I can only seem to get it to take the last filter set.  Can anyone provide me with information on how to stack them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Filter property is simply a delegate to a function that takes an object and returns a boolean.  That function can be as simple or as complex as you choose to write.

Sounds to me that you just need one function contain a series of `if` blocks that compares the object with each of your 6 fields as necessary then returns the result.

The point is there is no "set of filters" that you can "stack" you just write **a** filter function that does all you need it to do.